# Ice maker loud knocking noise

Tags: plumbing

The lower drawer freezer icemaker in my Frigidaire side by side refridgerator unit makes a very loud knocking sound every time ice cubes are dispensed.
The unit produces a good volume of ice cubes, but even when a handful of cubes are removed, the knocking sound is so loud, can be heard throughout the house

Comment: When does it make noise? For how long? More information, please.

Comment: your post would be clearer if you referred to `ice dispenser`  .... the `ice maker` is the part that actually makes ice

Comment: Is it a new development or has it always been like that?

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me often. Same brand and design. When this happens, I open the cover on the ice  bucket and knock out any ice cubes that are still stuck in the ice maker tray with a wooden spoon and then the noise stops...at least until the next time it dispenses more ice.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 2):

My Frigidaire ice maker also started making a knocking noise every few seconds. The bin was completely full. Emptied the bin but still knocking. My wife found a post about the ice maker fan stuck on ice or frost. The knock was the can trying to start up. Pulled the ice tray and blew a hair dryer in there for a minute. The knock stopped!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 0):

With the lack of complete info, we can only guess. My guess is that the mechanism that ejects the ice into the tray when ready is failing. These typically have a little electric motor driving some gears and cams, often made of nylon or other cold resistant plastic. There is a large driving gear being driven by a small (pinion) gear attached to the motor and if the teeth on either one start to wear down, they slip on each other, making a loud clicking or banging sound. Bottom line, it is about to fail completely, you need to replace it. Some can be repaired, some cannot and you replace the entire ice maker.
http://www.acmehowto.com/howto/appliance/icemaker/repair/ejectorgear.php

[image]

Comment: Thanks...that certainly could explain the short duration time and possibly the loud knocking sound. Not sure what other details I can provide to help determine root cause.